# What is the intuition behind SVD?

Tags: pca, matrix, intuition, linear-algebra, svd

I have read about singular value decomposition (SVD). In almost all textbooks it is mentioned that it factorizes the matrix into three matrices with given specification.

But what is the intuition behind splitting the matrix in such form? PCA and other algorithms for dimensionality reduction are intuitive in the sense that algorithm has nice visualization property but with SVD it is not the case.

Comment: You might want to start from the intuition of eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition as SVD is an extension of it for all kinds of matrices, instead of just square ones.

Comment: There are plenty of notes on internet and answers here on CV about SVD and its workings.

Comment: SVD can be thought as a compression/learning algorithm. It is a linear compressor decompressor. A matrix M can be represented by multiplication of SVD. S is the compressor V determines how much error you would like to have (lossy compression) and D is the decompressor. If you keep all diagonal values of V then you have a lossless compressor. If you start throwing away small singular values (zeroing them) then you cannot reconstruct the initial matrix exactly but will still be close. Here the term close is measured with Frobenius norm.

Comment: @Cagdas, +1, would you maybe like to expand this into a proper answer? You will have my +1.

Comment: @Cagdas if you do that please carefully define what you're taking "S" "V" and "D" to be mathematically. I've not seen the initials overloaded into the notation itself before (which has the singular values in it, for example?). It seems to be a likely source of confusion,

Comment: @Glen_b Yes I haven't followed the UDV* notation. They are just letters, and most sources are bogged down in math without any intuition anyhow.

Comment: Yes, but you then meed to make clear what the symbols represent, especially since you also have a D and a V

Comment: The notation I am used to is $USV^\top$.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc If it helps, the intuition regarding SVDs that I learned was that it was appropriate as a dimension reduction method for asymmetric matrices -- as already noted -- as well as non-normal, nonlinear as well as categorical scale types. So, if standard PCA is appropriate for continuously distributed, symmetric and linear data with finite moment structures, SVDs are generalizable to a much wider class of input information.

Comment: @DJohnson When you have an autoencoder that has a parameter which lets you throw away information in a decreasing manner with respect to a loss function (Frobenius norm in this case) you can use it as dimensionality reduction purposes. There are many other options. You can for example take Fourier transform of data and keep only terms with large absolute values. Or Discrete Cosine Transform like it is applied in JPEG.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc My point was about compatibility and tractability of the matrix operations between SVD and the inputs. Your point seems addressed to issues with dimension reduction of those inputs. Are we saying the same thing?

Comment: Do you know how to estimate PCA with SVD? If you do, then can you explain why you feel that something missing in your understanding of SVD? See [this](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lifeifei/cis5930/lecture12-a.pdf)

Comment: @Aksakal link's broken

Comment: Not purely intuitive, but should be easily understandable to anyone with basic linear algebra knowlege(or watch 3Blue1Brown's lin algebra videos):
http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-svd I found this really helpfull.

Comment: Just for fun: [the SVD song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEYLfIVvR9I).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen this song is underrated.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Write the SVD of matrix $X$ (real, $n\times p$) as
$$
   X = U D V^T
$$
where $U$ is $n\times p$, $D$ is diagonal $p\times p$ and $V^T$ is $p\times p$. In terms of the columns of the matrices $U$ and $V$ we can write
$X=\sum_{i=1}^p d_i u_i v_i^T$. That shows $X$ written as a sum of $p$ rank-1 matrices. What does a rank-1 matrix look like? Let's see:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 8 & 10 & 12 \\ 12 & 15 & 18 \end{pmatrix}
$$ The rows are proportional, and the columns are proportional.

Think now about $X$ as containing the grayscale values of a black-and-white image, each entry in the matrix representing one pixel.  For instance the following picture of a baboon:

[image: image of a baboon]

Then read this image into R and get the matrix part of the resulting structure, maybe using the library `pixmap`.

---

If you want a step-by-step guide as to how to reproduce the results, you can find the [code here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/SVD%20for%20image%20compression).

---

Calculate the SVD:

```r
    baboon.svd  <-  svd(bab) # May take some time
```

How can we think about this?  We get the $512 \times 512$ baboon image represented as a sum of $512$ simple images, with each one only showing vertical and horizontal structure, i.e. it is an image of vertical and horizontal stripes! So, the SVD of the baboon represents the baboon image as a superposition of $512$ simple images, each one only showing horizontal/vertical stripes.  Let us calculate a low-rank reconstruction of the image with $1$ and with $20$ components:

```r
    baboon.1  <-  sweep(baboon.svd$u[, 1, drop=FALSE], 2, 
                  baboon.svd$d[1], "*") %*%
                       t(baboon.svd$v[, 1, drop=FALSE])
    
    baboon.20 <-  sweep(baboon.svd$u[, 1:20, drop=FALSE], 2, 
                baboon.svd$d[1:20], "*") %*%
                       t(baboon.svd$v[ , 1:20, drop=FALSE])
```

resulting in the following two images:

[image: rank one and rank 20 reconstruction of baboon image]

On the left we can easily see the vertical/horizontal stripes in the rank-1 image.

Let us finally look at the "residual image", the image reconstructed (as above, code not shown) from the $20$ rank-one images with the lowest singular values. Here it is:

[image: image of residuals from rank 20 baboon reconstruction]

Which is quite interesting: we see the parts of the original image that are difficult to represent as superposition of vertical/horizontal lines,  mostly diagonal nose hair and some texture, and the eyes!

Comment: I think you meant low-rank reconstruction, not low range. Never mind. This is a very good illustration (+1). That's why it is a linear compressor decompressor. Image is approximated with lines. If you actually perform a similar autoencoder with a neural network with linear activation functions, you will actually see that it also allows lines with any slope not only vertical and horizontal lines, which makes it slightly more powerful than SVD.

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen Shouldn't the SVD $X = U \Sigma V^*$ for a $n \times p$ matrix $X$ result in $U$ being $n \times n$, $\Sigma$ being $n \times p$ and $V$ being $p \times p$? Typo?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/what-do-eigenvalues-have-to-do-with-pictures/92187#92187    for some other examples

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen I am interested in knowing how would the decription change if I would have used PCA for denosing application. I would appreciate if you could answer my question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412123/pca-vs-svd-difference-in-denoising-applications

Comment: @CowboyTrader interesting observation. My understanding of machine learning/neural network is pretty limited. So, I fail to understand that if one has a single noisy image and nothing else to train on, how would the neural network work?

Answer (score 19):

Let $A$ be a real $m \times n$ matrix. I'll assume that $m \geq n$ for simplicity. It's natural to ask in which direction $v$ does $A$ have the most impact (or the most explosiveness, or the most amplifying power). The answer is
\begin{align}
\tag{1}v_1 = \,\,& \arg \max_{v \in \mathbb R^n} \quad \| A v \|_2 \\
& \text{subject to } \, \|v\|_2 = 1.
\end{align}
A natural follow-up question is, after $v_1$, what is the next most explosive direction for $A$? The answer is
\begin{align}
v_2 = \,\,& \arg \max_{v \in \mathbb R^n} \quad \| A v \|_2 \\
& \text{subject to } \,\langle v_1, v \rangle = 0, \\
& \qquad \qquad \, \, \, \, \|v\|_2 = 1.
\end{align}
Continuing like this, we obtain an orthonormal basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$. This special basis of $\mathbb R^n$ tells us the directions that are, in some sense, most important for understanding $A$.

Let $\sigma_i = \|A v_i \|_2$ (so $\sigma_i$ quantifies the explosive power of $A$ in the direction $v_i$).  Suppose that unit vectors $u_i$ are defined so that
$$
\tag{2} A v_i = \sigma_i u_i \quad \text{for } i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$
The equations (2) can be expressed concisely using matrix notation as
$$
\tag{3} A V = U \Sigma,
$$
where $V$ is the $n \times n$ matrix whose $i$th column is $v_i$, $U$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $i$th column is $u_i$, and $\Sigma$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal matrix whose $i$th diagonal entry is $\sigma_i$. The matrix $V$ is orthogonal, so we can multiply both sides of (3) by $V^T$ to obtain
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T.
$$
It might appear that we have now derived the SVD of $A$ with almost zero effort. None of the steps so far have been difficult. However, a crucial piece of the picture is missing -- we do not yet know that the columns of $U$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Here is the crucial fact, the missing piece: it turns out that $A v_1$ is orthogonal to $A v_2$:
$$
\tag{4} \langle A v_1, A v_2 \rangle = 0.
$$
I claim that **if this were not true, then $v_1$ would not be optimal for problem (1).** Indeed, if (4) were not satisfied, then it would be possible to *improve* $v_1$ by perturbing it a bit in the direction $v_2$.

Suppose (for a contradiction) that (4) is not satisfied. If $v_1$ is perturbed slightly in the orthogonal direction $v_2$, the norm of $v_1$ does not change (or at least, the change in the norm of $v_1$ is negligible). **When I walk on the surface of the earth, my distance from the center of the earth does not change.** However, when $v_1$ is perturbed in the direction $v_2$, the vector $A v_1$ is perturbed in the *non-orthogonal* direction $A v_2$, and so the change in the norm of $A v_1$ is *non-negligible*. The norm of $A v_1$ can be increased by a non-negligible amount. This means that $v_1$ is not optimal for problem (1), which is a contradiction. I love this argument because: 1) the intuition is very clear; 2) the intuition can be converted directly into a rigorous proof.

A similar argument shows that $A v_3$ is orthogonal to both $A v_1$ and $A v_2$, and so on. The vectors $A v_1, \ldots, A v_n$ are pairwise orthogonal. This means that the unit vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ can be chosen to be pairwise orthogonal, which means the matrix $U$ above is an orthogonal matrix. This completes our discovery of the SVD.

---

To convert the above intuitive argument into a rigorous proof, we must confront the fact that if $v_1$ is perturbed in the direction $v_2$, the perturbed vector
$$
\tilde v_1 = v_1 + \epsilon v_2
$$
is not truly a unit vector. (Its norm is $\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2}$.) To obtain a rigorous proof, define
$$
\bar v_1(\epsilon) = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} v_1 + \epsilon v_2.
$$
The vector $\bar v_1(\epsilon)$ is truly a unit vector. But as you can easily show, if (4) is not satisfied, then for sufficiently small values of $\epsilon$ we have
$$
f(\epsilon) = \| A \bar v_1(\epsilon) \|_2^2 > \| A v_1 \|_2^2
$$
(assuming that the sign of $\epsilon$ is chosen correctly).
To show this, just check that $f'(0) \neq 0$.
This means that $v_1$ is not optimal for problem (1), which is a contradiction.

(By the way, I recommend reading Qiaochu Yuan's explanation of the SVD [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/). In particular, take a look at "Key lemma # 1", which is what we discussed above. As Qiaochu says, key lemma # 1 is "the technical heart of singular value decomposition".)

Comment: Love this answer. This is the best way to think about the SVD.

Comment: Fantastic answer! You made my day!

Answer (score 13):

Take an hour of your day and watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EokL7E6o1AE) lecture.

This guy is super straight-forward; It's important not to skip any of it because it all comes together in the end. Even if it might seem a little slow at the beginning, he is trying to pin down a critical point, which he does!

I'll sum it up for you, rather than just giving you the three matrices that everyone does (because that was confusing me when I read other descriptions). Where do those matrices come from and why do we set it up like that? The lecture nails it! Every matrix (ever in the history of everness) can be constructed from a base matrix with same dimensions, then rotate it, and stretch it (this is the fundamental theorem of linear algebra). Each of those three matrices people throw around represent an initial matrix (U), A scaling matrix (sigma), and a rotation matrix (V).

The scaling matrix shows you which rotation vectors are dominating, these are called the singular values. The decomposition is solving for U, sigma, and V.

Comment: Another useful lecture:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA66KsFqUAE