# Why PMI + SVD works for similarities arithmetics?

Tags: similarities, recommender-system, svd, word2vec

Recently Julia Silge blogged [here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/tidy-word-vectors/) and [here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/word-vectors-take-two/), quoting [blog entry](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/10/18/stop-using-word2vec/) by Chris Moody, who suggested that the similarities arithmetic in word2vec can be approximated by using [PMI indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) followed by [SVD decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177102/what-is-the-intuition-behind-svd). Word2vec is used to produce word vectors, that enables a user to do similarities arithmetics, e.g. *king - man + woman = queen*. As suggested in the blog entries, word2vec can be easily approximated using PMI indexes, i.e. $\log \tfrac{p(x,\,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}$, and then decomposing it using SVD.

My questions are, why exactly did they choose such combination of methods to approximate word2vec and why exactly does it work like intended? I understand why SVD can be used for recommender systems etc., but I am curious with such paring it with PMI.