# PCA new axes: always the same origin as the "original" axes?

Tags: pca, linear-model, dimensionality-reduction, linear-algebra

When we carry out PCA, is my understanding correct that the new principal components will need to agree on the same origin as the "original" axes of the data?

I have read through this great thread on PCA [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues): what confused me slightly is that the animations done by user Amoeba suggest the first PC does *not* need to go through the origin...

I always assumed that in linear algebra, whatever transformation we do, the origin has to remain the same (otherwise it's no longer linear...?)

Comment: In that animation, all the PCs share a common origin.

Comment: @whuber: thank you. But do all the PCs have to share the same origin as the **original data** ?

Comment: The data are usually centered before calculating the PCA. In that case, the PCs always have the same origin, namely $(0,0)$. Maybe the pictures in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22331/21054) help in understanding.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22329.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485405 might also be helpful.  The fact is that you're free to recenter any of the variables before performing PCA.

Comment: @whuber: thank you! That is very helpful.