# How can I interpret singular value decomposition analysis?

Tags: correlation, covariance, svd, singular-matrix, meteorology

I am trying to understand singular value decomposition analysis. I compared two gridded atmospheric data.

The Mode 1 has 79.5% squared covariance fraction. Modes 2 and 3 have 3% and 2%, respectively. From Mode 1 to 3, the Varf are 39, 12, 5, respectively. Then, there is heterogeneous correlation at 0.5, 0.4, 0.6 for Modes 1 to 3.

My question is how to interpret these values or what are these  values/numbers? What is scf and how is it different from varf? What is a heterogeneous correlation and how is it different from the homogeneous one? I get frustrated by the lack of online reference on this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca/134283?r=SearchResults#134283) answer your question?

Comment: @mhdadk I did not find the discussion on what is the purpose of SCF, VARF, among other things. I was actually looking for straightforward answers and not on the mathematical/theoretical aspect of SVD.

Comment: Could you tell us some details on how you compared gridded data? SVD on what? The difference of the grids? ... also explain your abbrevs, and have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177102/what-is-the-intuition-behind-svd.  Maybe you can do interpretation via reconstructions?